# Initalization [sic] Guy

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Quick question.  I just reviewed 10 suggested edits ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9883917)) where the user only corrected the word "initialization" (or variations of such word).  I looked at their profile and noticed that they basically searched for questions that had the word "initialization" in them and corrected the spelling (which I must add is a genius way to get 2 points).  I seemed to be in the minority when rejecting these edits. Are these types of edits accepts?

Comment: Exactly i was going to ask this too. i rejected all. i choosed `cause harm` and described that this is spamming edit. however im not sure if i get banned from reviewing again or not (because once i got banned). also im curios if system is capable of finding such spams with one user or not.

Comment: He has 7 answers and 3 questions and a 1.2k rep.  Seems to be chronic.

Comment: I spend all my reviews on rejecting those edits.

Comment: I encountered almost a dozen.  But I approved them, because it did improve the post and made it searchable.  On the flip side, they were trivial.  So, maybe a moderator should have a word with him.

Comment: I guess my only concern is a guy with 10 combined posts is 400 grammatical corrections away from doing whatever he wants.

Comment: @RohitGupta I think 2015 google search can discern between "initialization" vs "initalization".  The edit making it more "searchable" is stretch.

Comment: @GoBrewers14, He has already had 500 edits approved, so he is not getting any more rep for them.  Maybe he hasn't realised it yet.

Comment: @RohitGupta he is getting rep. as i saw him about 6 hours ago he had about 1100 rep and now its 1200 ,sure he wont get more rep for edits after 2000. but you should not accept such edits. you are giving him rep thus more access to the site and s/he cant really be useful for stackoverflow for just editing questions like that and then imagine s/he can edit what ever s/he wants while doesnt understand how this site actually works. i think stackoverflow should ban this kind of action.

Comment: @theB, thats not my understanding.  I certainly only got 1000 rep (for 500 edits) even though my total rep was below 2000 then.  Refer here http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: @RohitGupta - I'm apparently a moron. :) I've read, and directed people to that page a ton of times, and my reading comprehension still sucks.  I'll delete that comment.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, Okay, you guys have changed my mind.  Is there any way I can find them and reverse them ?